# Using axios in Nuxt asyncData lose token on browser refresh

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, token, asyncdata

I am getting the meta tags from an API using `asyncData` in Axios in Nuxt but my problem is that the meta description have to be set server side to appear in the code.
So I added the following my nuxt page :

```js
asyncData(context) {
  return context.$axios
    .get('/api/house', {
      headers: {
        'X-AUTH-TOKEN': '######',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      return { fetchedData: res.data.page.meta }
    })
},
```

At first the meta description is there in the code but if I refresh the browser I lose my token.

I tried to add it in the **nuxt.config.js** with:

```js
axios: {
  headers: {
    common: {
      'X-AUTH-TOKEN': '###################',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  },
},
```

Like this I was thinking that every axios `GET` request will have the token server side without being lost but it doesn't work. So I tried to set up an axios interceptor making an `axios.js` and adding it in **nuxt.config.js** :

```js
plugins: [
  { src: '~/plugins/axios.js' },  
]
```

my **axios.js** :

```js
import axios from 'axios'

const AUTH_TOKEN = '#######################'

axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN

axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
```

But the result is still the same everytime I refresh my Nuxt page, the token disappears and because I use `asyncData` the page does not render.

How can I set up my meta description with `asyncData` and add my token to every `GET` request even if I refresh my browser?

******EDIT******

Here is how i make my cliend side request in my nuxt page for the meta tags:

```html
<script>
export default {
  layout: 'house',

  asyncData(context) {
    return context.$axios
      .get('/api/house', {
        headers: {
          'X-AUTH-TOKEN': '### TOKEN HARDCODED ###',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        return { fetchedData: res.data.page.meta }
      })
  },

  data() {
    return {
      route: 'house',
      fetchedData: [],
    }
  },
  head() {
    return {
      title: this.fetchedData.title,
      meta: [
        { charset: 'utf-8' },
        { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
        { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: this.fetchedData.description },
      ],
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should focus on your first code snippet and see why the token is not present at this time. Do you have it hardcoded or are you fetching it from somewhere ? More of an async issue more than a configuration one tbh.

Comment: Thank you for answering me the token is hardcoded in the page yes

Comment: Btw, what do you mean by "meta description have to be set server side" ? You cannot make the call on the client ? It's a basic API, no ? Try making it on the client and look for what you're sending to the backend in your network devtools.

Comment: Because if i dont use asyncData getting it server side the meta description content appear "undefined" i tried to get it client side with : async mounted() {
    await axios ...} but only the meta title appear

Comment: You're using `asyncData` server side ? That means that your app is *universal* and that you disable your client side JS just to try this one ? I just want to be sure that you understand that `asyncData` is both server **and** client side and from what I can see, the call you're making here is client side. Btw, it should totally work client side too. Does it work with a Postman-like request ? We can probably try to see why it is not working client side, because the error may come from here.

Comment: Ok kissu im using asyncData client side your right my app is universal yes i understand thank you to explain me in postman i got all the data so normally it should work client side for the meta description i think my code is wrong certainly if we can see why it is not working client side it will be great

Comment: Edit your question and show us how you do make your client side call, that way we will be able to debug it. :)

Comment: Try to use NuxtAuth https://auth.nuxtjs.org/

Comment: @KubiRoazhon not really a good recommendation to start with this module since it's not the best explained. The fact is: a lot of people do struggle with it as of right now for various reasons. So rather stay simple and use some basic vanilla axios for now IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so here is a codesandbox to show you the working example with a test fake API: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-async-data-nuxt-axios-get-f4y3v?file=/pages/index.vue

And here is the actual interesting code

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>fetched data below</p>
    <p>{{ fetchedData }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ $axios, $config: { secureToken } }) { // import your env varibles here
    const response = await $axios.$get( // $get shortcut, https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage#-shortcuts
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
      {
        headers: {
          'X-AUTH-TOKEN': secureToken,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      }
    )
    return { fetchedData: response }
  },
}
</script>
```

Of course, you can hardcode the `secureToken` but here, I showed you how to use an env variable.

This is a part of the `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
export default {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    secureToken: process.env.SECURE_TOKEN,
  },
  ...
}
```

You should put into a `.env` file.

```
SECURE_TOKEN="### TOKEN HARDCODED ###"
```

It will of course need to be blacklisted from the `.gitignore` (default behavior btw). I committed it for **example purposes**, do not expose it publicly. Use env variables on your server ! :)

Once this is working, you could look into some axios global configuration. Let me know if this one works properly before going ahead.

Comment: wowo Thank you Kissu it work so WELL ... i create a .env with my Token your right its better for security and use your example i can get the meta description in all pages thats so great ... now  because i use the proxy option in axios i have to fix why i got a cors policy problem  when i change route switching pages..